# Does a HIVE table get duplicated across all nodes of a Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

When I create a HIVE table, does the table get created on all nodes of the Hadoop Cluster? When I load the data into the table, does the data get replicated across all these nodes?

My guess is yes?

Comment: since `HIVE` uses `HDFS` as storage, the replication of the data is taken care by `NameNode`...I do not think replication of Hive table data is taken care separately ..

Answer (score 0):

Hive is just a metadata layer on top of `hdfs`. So to answer your question you would want to simply think about how replication works within `hdfs`.

Your question about "on each node" is just not the correct mental model of how `hdfs` replication works. `hdfs` replication knows/cares nothing at all about hive tables. It only knows about data blocks.

There will be K copies of each data block of the hive table - where k is the replication factor configured for the given hive table.  The association of the data blocks to particular nodes is driven by the local/rack/cluster location policy of hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

> When I create a HIVE table, does the table get created on all nodes of
>   the Hadoop Cluster?

**No.**
Hadoop datanodes are **not** mirror images of each other. These are just data storage units whose the storage and meta is managed by NameNode.

Your hive table will be replicated based on the replication factor set. If your replication factor is one, there will only be one copy.

> When I load the data into the table, does the data get replicated
>   across all these nodes?

**No.**
As I specified earlier, hadoop datanodes are not mirror images of each other so they all don't contain all the data. They just contain the defined number of copies of data in the cluster(based on the replication factor set).

The data loaded by you gets replicated based on the replication factor (on nodes decided by the NameNode).